# How do I report a spam content on Wikipedia?

Tags: spam-prevention, wikipedia

I was reading biography of a diseased columnist. I saw that the newspaper company of his has put its logo behind his pictures, and mentioning their company name a lot of place in the page profusely.

I want to report this situation, but I don't know how to do it. I found [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikiProject_Spam) for reporting spam on Wikipedia, but I didn't understand how to do it. Can you please explain it over an example. Assume that the page for [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom) on Wikipedia were containing spammy content; assume that the large [photo of Helium nucleus](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aHelium_atom_QM.svg) on the top of that page were a spammy image. What steps should I do to report it? Please explain it as you are explaining it for dummies.

Answer (score 4):

[The page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikiProject_Spam) you link to has a big red button with the following text underneath

> Use this button to report spam abuse. This will create a new section/report on the talk page.

Click that button and it takes you to a new page where you can report the spam. You need to one of the specified templates:

`{{IP summary|127.0.0.1}}` -- *to report anonymous editors*
`{{User summary|Username}}` -- *to report registered users*
`{{Link summary|example.com}}` -- *to report spam domains*

and sign the post.

Give as much information as you can.

Nothing will be recorded until you save your edits.

Comment: That page already contained the information you gave in your answer. I said that I didn't understand it. Those templates confuse me. I need an example usage of those templates.

Comment: @hkBattousai - what in particular is confusing you? Have you tried doing what it asks?

Comment: I just want an example. Is this format correct: `{{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Helium_atom_QM.svg This picture contains advertisement of a newspaper in which the columnist had worked.|http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom}}`. Please add an example usage like this in your answer.